# Minecraft 1.10 Custom Spawn Eggs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way to make a spawn egg spawn a mob with an NBT tag or a custom Loot Table?

If there is, will it work if I put the spawn egg in a monster spawner?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to make a spawn egg spawn a mob with an NBT tag or a custom Loot Table?

Yes, add the tags you want in `EntityTag`. For example:

```
/give @p spawn_egg 1 0 {EntityTag:{id:Creeper,powered:1b,DeathLootTable:"minecraft:empty"}}
```

---

> If there is, will it work if I put the spawn egg in a monster spawner?

No, you will need to edit the data of the mob spawner separately. For example:

```
/blockdata X Y Z {SpawnPotentials:[{Entity:{id:Creeper,powered:1b,DeathLootTable:"minecraft:empty"}}]}
```